# How to prevent "OptionTransfer init(): Left select list does not exist in form" alert box from javascript

Tags: php, javascript, smarty, testlink

I have testlink setup install on my machine and I am trying to learn it. The issue is while creating and editing test case it showing the following alert box containing :

```
OptionTransfer init(): Left select list does not exist in form!
```

I alert is coming while clicking on add/edit test case button. I investigated the issue and found the source from its coming.

```
//function OT_init(theform){this.form = theform;if(!theform[this.left]){alert("OptionTransfer init(): Left select list does not exist in form!");return false;}if(!theform[this.right]){alert("OptionTransfer init(): Right select list does not exist in form!");return false;}this.left=theform[this.left];this.right=theform[this.right];for(var i=0;i<this.left.options.length;i++){this.originalLeftValues[this.left.options[i].value]=1;}for(var i=0;i<this.right.options.length;i++){this.originalRightValues[this.right.options[i].value]=1;}if(this.removedLeftField!=null){this.removedLeftField=theform[this.removedLeftField];}if(this.removedRightField!=null){this.removedRightField=theform[this.removedRightField];}if(this.addedLeftField!=null){this.addedLeftField=theform[this.addedLeftField];}if(this.addedRightField!=null){this.addedRightField=theform[this.addedRightField];}if(this.newLeftField!=null){this.newLeftField=theform[this.newLeftField];}if(this.newRightField!=null){this.newRightField=theform[this.newRightField];}this.update();}
```

So I just putted comments over there on that function but the issue is still persist and its still showing the error.

I also checked the add/edit(both in same file) and found that there is no any issue.

I am searching from last 2 days and not getting any solution :

So my question is :

1) Why its showing the following alert?

2) I commented the function still why its showing alert?

3) Is it related to the html `<select>` tag?

4) How should I prevent this?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You have a page using [Matt Kruse's OptionTransfer widget](http://www.mattkruse.com/javascript/optiontransfer/index.html).  When it initialises it looks up the select elements within the widget's html.  The init function should be called with the parent form element as the parameter.

I had this issue too.  In my case the init function was being called with the wrong parameter (a nearby div) so the select was not being found an so giving this error.  Probably something similar in your case.